# Generating set for $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Let
\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{\lambda}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
be a matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb{C}$). I am trying to prove that $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is generated by the matrices
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & z\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
z & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
for $z\in\mathbb{C}$. I have already handled all the cases expect for matrices like $A$. How can I write it as a product of matrices of this type? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Multiplying by those two matrices on the left or right correspond to row or column operations where you add $z$ times a row or column to the remaining row or column. So the question becomes whether you can turn $A$ into the identity matrix using row and column operations (without allowing scalar multiplication.)

Comment: So your question is easier and the answer is a special case of the answer given there.

Comment: @JCAA: I see, I will try if I can apply it to this case

Comment: @JCAA: It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\lambda \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
\frac{1}{\lambda} & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
-1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
\lambda - 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Did you come up with this by performing row and column operations as mentioned in the comments above?

Comment: @physicist23 Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485648/transvection-matrices-generate-operatornamesl-n-mathbbr?noredirect=1&lq=1) provided by JCAA, we can also come up with a way of generating $A$ in terms of four matrices. Following the procedure there yields
\begin{equation}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda^2} & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \lambda\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
\frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda} & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}